# Leaflet map event equivalent to Google Map "idle" event

Tags: google-maps, leaflet

I can't seem to find the map event in Leaflet that equals to Google Map "idle" event.

The definition of Google Map event "idle" is "This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming."

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

I tried Leaflet "viewreset", "load", "blur", "focused", "moveend" but they are really different from Google Map's "idle".

- "viewreset": only executed when finished zoom in/out, not on initial and after panning.
- "load": only when initialized.
- "moveend": only when panning and zoomed, not initialized.

The best I can do is to use this

```
var foo = function(e){
   console.log('Hello');
}
map.on('load', foo);
map.on('moveend', foo);
```

Just want to find out if I'm reading the manual wrong. Or even if there is no event equivalent to Google Map's 'idle', is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You are correct that there is no "idle" event built in, but I am sure you can trigger your logic without it.

Comment: Just want to find out if I'm reading the manual wrong. Or even if there is no event equivalent to Google Map's 'idle', is there a better way to implement it.

Comment: Nevertheless, when someone's trying to port their map from Google Map to Leaflet and google about what's the equivalent of 'idle' event, they can find it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "idle" event in Leaflet library, though the description seems resemblant of "moveend" (there is nothing about map initialization).

As you yourself found out, you can use both "load" and "moveend" events. For catching those two, you don't need to call `map.on` twice: events can be joined in one string:

```
map.on('load moveend', function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: The problem with this is moveend can be called too much and thus cause unnecessary rendering. Is there a plugin that adds an idle like feature otherwise debouncing will need to be done.

Comment: @Nick an issue has been logged about the need for idle (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3178).